# Remove hyperlink from post title in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Having trouble getting rid of href in order to have post title without link

```
the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" title="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ), '</a></h2>' );
```

Comment: the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title">', esc_url( get_permalink() ), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ), '</h2>' );

Comment: Works great ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title">', esc_url( get_permalink() ), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ), '</h2>' );<br />
```

Try this and tell if works.